# Tikz: Draw lines between edges of rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}   
    \newcommand{\opacity}{0.6}      
        \begin{tikzpicture}                             
        \draw[xshift=1cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0) -- (3,3) -- (3.2,3) -- (0.2,0) -- (0,0);
        \draw[xshift=2cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (2.2,2) -- (0.2,0) -- (0,0);  
        \draw[xshift=3cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1.2,1) -- (0.2,0) -- (0,0);        
        \end{tikzpicture}      
    \end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

How can I connect the edges of the rectangles with a line? I don't want to use coordinates (`\draw (0,0) -- (2,2)`) but rather something like

`\draw (rectangle1.north east) -- (rectangle2.north west)`.

It would also be great if there is a solution like:

```
\draw (A1)(0,0) -- (B1)(1,1) -- (C1)(1.2,1) -- (D1)(0.2,0) -- (E1)(0,0);
\draw (A2)(0,0) -- (B2)(1,1) -- (C2)(1.2,1) -- (D2)(0.2,0) -- (E2)(0,0);
\draw (A1) -- (C2)
```

Comment: at drawed shapes this is not possible. they haven't defined names nor anchors. you can do this by use of `coordinates` for each shape corner, but this will cause quite complex code. for example for the first shape: `\draw[myshape]  (0,0) coordinate (A1) -- 
                (3,3) coordinate (A2) -- 
                (3.2,3) coordinate (A3) -- 
                (0.2,0) coordinate (A4) -- cycle;` and than draw for example `draw (A1) -- (A3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}   
    \newcommand{\opacity}{0.6}      
        \begin{tikzpicture}                             
        \draw[xshift=1cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0)coordinate(A1) -- (3,3)coordinate(A2) -- (3.2,3)coordinate(A3) -- (0.2,0) coordinate(A4) -- cycle;
        \draw[xshift=2cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0)coordinate(B1) -- (2,2)coordinate(B2) -- (2.2,2)coordinate(B3) -- (0.2,0)coordinate(B4) -- cycle;  
        \draw[xshift=3cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity] 
        (0,0)coordinate(C1) -- (1,1) coordinate(C2)-- (1.2,1)coordinate(C3) -- (0.2,0)coordinate(C4) -- cycle; 

        \draw(A4)--(B1);
        \draw(B4)--(C1);
        \draw(A3)--(B3)--(C3);

        \end{tikzpicture}      
    \end{document}
```

**Update using a foreach loop**:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}   
    \newcommand{\opacity}{0.6}      
        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \foreach \xs/\p/\x in{1/A/3,2/B/2,3/C/1}
        {\draw[xshift=\xs cm,fill=gray,draw=black,opacity=\opacity]
        (0,0)coordinate(\p1)
        --(\x,\x)coordinate(\p2)
        --(\x+0.2,\x)coordinate(\p3)
        --(0.2,0)coordinate(\p4)
        --cycle;}

   \draw(A4)--(B1);
   \draw(B4)--(C1);
   \draw(A3)--(B3)--(C3);

        \end{tikzpicture}      
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible, that `\draw(A-4)--(B-1);` should be `\draw(A4)--(B1);`? The same probably also applies to the other cases.

Comment: @Samuel Yes it is perfectly possible! Just replace `coordinate(\p-1)`,...,`coordinate(\p-4)` with   `coordinate(\p1)`,...,`coordinate(\p4)` . I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your post, if two coordinates are given, the full shape is fixed. Your shape is not a rectangle, but a trapezium, and there are predefined shapes available.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my trapez/.style={trapezium,%inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,
trapezium left angle=135, trapezium right angle=45,rotate=45,
minimum width={#1*sqrt(2)*1cm},minimum height={sqrt(2)*1mm},draw,fill=gray,
 trapezium stretches body,anchor=west}]
\node[my trapez=3]  (L)    at (1,0) {};
\node[my trapez=2]  (M)    at (2,0) {};
\node[my trapez=1]  (R)    at (3,0) {};
\draw ([xshift=-sqrt(2)*1mm]L.west) -- ([xshift=sqrt(2)*1mm]R.west); 
\draw ([xshift=sqrt(2)*1mm]L.east) -- ([xshift=sqrt(2)*1mm]R.east); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, there are two mild problems with this approach:

1. it is nontrivial to control the dimensions precisely, at least for this shape;
2. to specify the position precisely, you need to think a bit. (This is also the case in Zarko's otherwise nice answer.)

Therefore, I'd like to propose a different route, in which you to draw and fill the thing as a decoration, which also lets you name the coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{trapez width/.initial=0.2cm,
my trapez/.style={decorate,decoration={
show path construction,
lineto code={\filldraw
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate(#1-south west) 
-- (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate(#1-north west)
-- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/trapez width}]\tikzinputsegmentlast)
coordinate(#1-north east)
-- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/trapez width}]\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
coordinate(#1-south east) -- cycle;
}}}}

\begin{document}   
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[fill=gray,opacity=0.6]
    \draw[my trapez=L] (1,0) -- (4,3);
    \draw[my trapez=M] (2,0) -- (4,2);
    \draw[my trapez=R] (3,0) -- (4,1);
   \end{scope}
   \draw (L-north east) --  (R-north east)
   (L-south west) --    (R-south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you really only need to specify two coordinates, which will become precisely named coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

let me elaborate my comment:

- for shapes, which you draw as you show in your mwe, this is not possible
- those shapes haven't defined names nor anchors.
- you can do this by use of coordinates for each shape corner, but this can result in quite complex code. for example for the first shape:

  ```
  \draw[myshape] (0,0) coordinate (A1) -- 
                 (3,3) coordinate (A2) -- 
                 (3.2,3) coordinate (A3) -- 
                 (0.2,0) coordinate (A4) -- cycle;
  ```

  and than draw for example

  ```
  \draw (A1) -- (A3);
  ```
- a way to simplify this code extension can be use of the small pictures: `\pic` (for details about it see chapter **18 Pics: Small Pictures on Paths** in *Tikz & PGF manual, v 3.0.1a, page 251*):

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
  pics/myshape/.style = {code={ % definition of your shape
      \draw[fill=gray,opacity=\opacity]
          ( 0.0,0) coordinate (-1) -- ++  % south west
          ( 0.2,0) coordinate (-2) -- ++  % south east
          (#1,#1)  coordinate (-3) -- ++  % north east, coordinate is determined by parameter #1
          (-0.2,0) coordinate (-4) --     % north west
          cycle;}}
                         ]
  \def\opacity{0.6}
  \pic (A) [above right] at (0,0) {myshape={3}}; % "3" is parameter which define size of shape
  \pic (B) [above right] at (1,0) {myshape={2}};
  \pic (C) [above right] at (2,0) {myshape={1}};
  \draw[very thin, red, densely dashed]
      (A-3) -- (B-3); % instead of \draw (rectangle1.north east) -- (rectangle2.north west).
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```
- for coordinates name you can select more meaningful names. for example instead of `-1` may be more appropriate `-sw`, which can associate you on "south west", etc.

[image]